# Edittext background image

Tags: android

when I set the background of my editText with "setBackgroundResource", everything works fine. When I use "setBackgroundDrawable" with the same image it ends up stretched ...

The result with "setBackgroundResource" on the left, "setBackgroundDrawable" on the right :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQi5n.jpg
(sorry I'm not allowed to post images here ...)

The code :

```
View chips = EditChipsActivity.this.findViewById(mydID);
chips.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.chips_filter);
```

VS :

```
View chips = EditChipsActivity.this.findViewById(mydID);
Bitmap bkg = ((BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.chips_filter)).getBitmap();
BitmapDrawable bkg = new BitmapDrawable(bkg);
chips.setBackgroundDrawable(bkg);
```

(I have to create my own bitmap and use the setBackgroundDrawable because I want to draw on the background)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
View chips = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    Bitmap bkg = ((BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.chips_filter)).getBitmap();
    BitmapDrawable bkgbt = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bkg);
    chips.setBackgroundDrawable((Drawable) bkgbt);
```

And your EditText:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </EditText>
```

I'm not if this do what you want....

Comment: Perfect ! I have just add the "getResources()" to the BitmapDrawable constructor and it works. It works without the "wrap_content" too.

Comment: Ok:) Like you can see here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html#BitmapDrawable(android.graphics.Bitmap), the constructor `BitmapDrawable (Bitmap bitmap)` is deprecated...

Comment: oh yes that's strange eclipse didn't put the usual yellow underline on it .

Comment: hey @amp, i got strange effect when tried your solutions. I mean, i tried to put my animated gif as the image, but then seems the image is stretched all over the edittext. and the image isn't animated. So how to overcome this case?